java: The true type of the generic cannot be obtained by reflection
class A<T, TT> {
}

class B<T, TT> extends A<T, TT> {
}


@Test
void TestGetGenericType_B() {
    B<String, Integer> b = new B();
    Type bType = b.getClass().getGenericSuperclass();
    ParameterizedType parameterizedType = (ParameterizedType) bType;
    Type[] actualTypeArguments = parameterizedType.getActualTypeArguments();
    for (Type actualTypeArg : actualTypeArguments) {
        System.out.println(actualTypeArg);
    }
}


println:
T
TT
The output I need is the type String and Integer when the variable is declared：
B<String, Integer> b = new B();

Oddly enough, the type of the generic can be obtained correctly in the following way！
class C extends A<String, Integer> {
}

@Test
void TestGetGenericType_C() {
    C c = new C();
    Type bType = c.getClass().getGenericSuperclass();
    ParameterizedType parameterizedType = (ParameterizedType) bType;
    Type[] actualTypeArguments = parameterizedType.getActualTypeArguments();
    for (Type actualTypeArg : actualTypeArguments) {
        System.out.println(actualTypeArg);
    }
}


println:
class java.lang.String
class java.lang.Integer
But I need to be able to get the type of generic correctly by executing the TestGetGenericType_B() method, Who can help me? thank you!

I've also run into situations where I can't get the List generic, for example: List list = new ArrayList(), Again, I can't get the actual element type String of the List correctly, just like my question above.

Thank you very much for your attention, I have tried many ways to get the type of List generics, but I still haven't solved it, the above case I developed from List, if there is a way to solve the above problem, then the problem of getting List generic types can also be solved

@DawoodibnKareem: I'm wrong, and so I have deleted my erroneous comments.

new B<>() only solves the problem of the rawtypes warning.  Fundamentally, what you want is impossible, and the only correct answer to your question is that you can't.

@HovercraftFullOfEels - bother, I was so sure you were right.  I guess I need to delete my comments too!

The annotation @Test suggests that this is a unit test but what are you testing here?

That's not how java works. What you want is not possible.

The output I need is the type String and Integer when the variable is declared：
B<String, Integer> b = new B();

That really really is not how it works. Java variables (unless they are of a primitive type) are pointers (except in java parlance, these are called references. Same principle). It's like the address in an address book. It is an instruction on how to get to a house. The house itself isn't in the address book. Given:
Color c = new Color(1, 2, 3);

c isn't the color. c is an address to a color. It's a pointer. And . is 'follow the address and do something to the house'.
So when you write b.getClass(), that's asking questions about the object produced with the new B() expression. not b the variable itself.
Hence, it would make no sense whatsoever if your code produced String.
It gets worse: Even if you had written  B<String, Integer> tt = new B<String, Integer>(); you couldn't get at it.
Generics are almost entirely a figment of the compiler's imagination. The problem is, if new B<String, Integer>() is an object that can be asked 'hey, uh, what were the generics you were made with?' that means said object needs to store that info somewhere. That takes memory. More fundamentally perhaps that was not possible to combine with existing code, and generics, whilst 15+ years old at this point, wasn't in java 1.0.
Point is, that info is simply not available. If the compiler does not know then it is not possible to tell.

class C extends A<String, Integer>

Any generics in signatures (in the return type or parameter types of a method, in the parameter types of a constructor, generics declared on a method or constructor itself, any extends / implements clauses, and the type of a field) is preserved in the class files. As far as The JVM (java.exe) is concerned, these are literally comments: the JVM does not know what generics are in any way; it knows what they look like in a class file (otherwise java couldn't read class files, that'd make it useless), but the only reason it knows that is so that it knows how to skip them because the generics being present in a class file is solely so that javac can do the right thing when compiling source code against a bunch of class files.
Hence why signatures retain them, but anywhere else, they are gone. In your statement B<String, Integer> tt = new B();, that is not a signature (it isn't a method parameter, return type, field type, or extends/implements clause) therefore what you want does not exist. There is literally ZERO difference in the class file between foo and bar in:
void foo() {
  List<String> x = new ArrayList<String>();
}

void bar() {
  List<Integer> x = new ArrayList<Integer>();
}

Try it; compile em both, decompile with javap or investigate the bytes: Bit for bit identical. If the above 2 look identical after compilation, then obviously at runtime no method could possibly tell you which one of the 2 was used to generate that class file.
You can recover generics in signatures but you recover only what the compiler knew. So, given, say:
class MyList<T> extends List<T> {}

If you then try to ask MyList.class (or even new MyList<String>().getClass()) what the generics are, it will tell you: T. Not String; that is erased and cannot possibly be recovered at runtime. It's not a matter of 'with enough tricky code you can do it' or 'the core libraries do not have a method to do it, but someone could write one'. No, impossible - the info you need to do that job simply is not there anymore.
Generics is a tool that lets the compiler tell you there's a typing mistake. That is the only thing it does - and that's why the compiler just ditches all generics info (other than in signatures, which it needs solely so that future invocations of javac can do its job).
You might want to look into super type tokens (STTs) if you need to convey generics in a way that can be introspected at runtime. They look like this:
SuperTypeToken<List<Map<String, ? super Integer>>> stt = new SuperTypeToken<>() {};

The {} at the end makes that an anonymous class, which technically means we now have a class definition with extends SuperTypeToken<List<Map<String, ? super Integer>>> tacked on to it, and, yay, that's a signature, so preserved, and at runtime we can get at it.
Some basic code snippets showing how to use STTs here.
Note that STTs require that your callers write them, with the generics you want. You can't get around the 'it is erased' part with this trickery; you  can't write e.g:
<T> Class<?> getFancy(List<T> list) {
  SuperTypeToken<List<T>> stt = new SuperTypeToken<List<T>>() {};
  return ??????;
}

void test() {
  List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
  Class<?> c = getFancy(list);
  assert c == String.class;
}

There's nothing that can go in the ????? that make this work. The only way to make STTs work is that the code that knows the actual type makes it; test() has to write literally new SuperTypeToken<List<String>>() {} if you want an object that you can at runtime ask for List<String> in some form.

Thank you for your patient analysis. My actual requirement is that the program can correctly obtain the generic type specified by the declared variable when running. In theory, the generic type has already been defined when declaring the variable, and the program should be able to obtain its type when running. I tested that C # can correctly retrieve the declared generic type at runtime.

If the variable declaration is encapsulated in Class as a field and the Field object is obtained through reflection, the generic type can be correctly obtained.
ParameterizedType parameterizedType = (ParameterizedType) field.getGenericType();

Type[] actualTypeArguments = parameterizedType.getActualTypeArguments();

Class<?> ***genericType*** = (Class<?>) actualTypeArguments[0];

Here, genericType can correctly obtain generic types

@dj-allan A 'variable declaration' as a term is kinda hard to apply to a field declaration. "Variable" is to "Field" in java as "Square" is to "Circle". C# is completely, utterly different from java in this regard: They do reify, java does not. I'm going to spell it out for you because apparently you have a hard time figuring it out: It is not possible in java. At all. The caller has to supply an STT. That's the only option.
